# Javascript file crashed and converted to ''NUL NUL NUL" notepad++

Tags: javascript, windows, notepad++

I had a for loop with typo `(i=0; i<n; i+3)`, then it ate all the memory, I had to shutdown
the PC and and after restart the `JS` file is all `NUL NUL NUL NUL NUL`, please help.

Please help me recover the code.
Thanks

Is it recoverable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if the file exists in any of the two places?

**%AppData%/Notepad++/plugins/config/NppFTP/Cache**

**%AppData%/Notepad++/backup**

Comment: No :(, no cache/backup plugin. Is it gone?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems so, unless you've got a periodic backup or restore point set up in your pc after the file was created. Also, this is a known issue with Notepad++ hence I use sublime text.